# Change background colour of a tile on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have added tiles on my map. What I want now is : on map click, I want to change background colour of the tile clicked on. How do I get to to that? is it even possible?

The code i have used ,in order to add tiles to my map is(from google maps api v3):

```
<script> 

  function CoordMapType(tileSize) {
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
  }

  CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
    div.style.fontSize = '10';
    div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
    return div;
  };

  var map;
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033,-87.6500523);

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: chicago,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                                      mapOptions);

    // Insert this overlay map type as the first overlay map type at
    // position 0. Note that all overlay map types appear on top of
    // their parent base map.
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
        0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256)));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using version 3, you can do this - http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries